# Numpy (sparse) repeated index increment

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, scipy, sparse-matrix

`a`, `b` are 1D `numpy` `ndarray` of same size with integer data type.

`C` is a 2D `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix`.

If the indexing `[a, b]` contains repeated index, does `C[a, b] += np.array([1])` always increment `C` exactly once for each unique indexing of `C` by `[a, b]`?

Did the documentation mention this?

Example:

```
import scipy.sparse as ss
import numpy as np
C = ss.lil_matrix((3,2), dtype=int)
a = np.array([0, 1, 2] * 4)
b = np.array([0, 1] * 6)
C[a, b] += np.array([1])
print(C.todense(), '\n')
C[a, b] += np.array([1])
print(C.todense())
```

Result:

```
[[1 1]
 [1 1]
 [1 1]] 

[[2 2]
 [2 2]
 [2 2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that it's documented

It's well known that dense arrays are set just once per unique index due to buffering.  We have to use `add.at` to get unbuffered addition.

```
In [966]: C=sparse.lil_matrix((3,2),dtype=int)
In [967]: Ca=C.A
In [968]: Ca += 1
In [969]: Ca
Out[969]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]])

In [970]: Ca=C.A
In [973]: np.add.at(Ca,(a,b),1)
In [974]: Ca
Out[974]: 
array([[2, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 2]])
```

Your example shows that the `lil` indexed setting behaves in the buffered sense as well.  But I'd have to look at the code to see exactly why.

It is documented that `coo` style inputs are summed across duplicates.

```
In [975]: M=sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones_like(a),(a,b)), shape=(3,2))
In [976]: print(M)
  (0, 0)    1
  (1, 1)    1
  (2, 0)    1
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (2, 1)    1
  (0, 0)    1
  (1, 1)    1
  (2, 0)    1
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (2, 1)    1
In [977]: M.A
Out[977]: 
array([[2, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 2]])
In [978]: M
Out[978]: 
<3x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 12 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [979]: M.tocsr()
Out[979]: 
<3x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [980]: M.sum_duplicates()
In [981]: M
Out[981]: 
<3x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 6 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

points are stored in `coo` format as entered, but when used for display or calculation (csr format) duplicates are summed.